Телеграм Бот не пересылает сообщение с медиа
Столкнулся с проблемой из за нехватки знаний и опыта. Совсем недавно заинтересовала тема питона и телеграм ботов.
Создал первый бот на площадке telebot creator и пытаюсь переслать в приватный канал сообщение с прикрепленными фотографиями. Но проблема в том, что бот пересылает только сообщения без медиа. А как сделать с медиа банально не доганяю а GPT не понимает, пишет для консоли...
Вот простой код
GROUP_ID = "*******"
if msg:
bot.forwardMessage(GROUP_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)

И Чтобы я не пробовал, как только прикрепляю фото, все молчит...
Ребята, только не гнобите, я только начал...
Заранее всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Распечайте вообще что там содержится в сообщении, в интернете пишут что когда сообщение содержить несколько медиа, то это уже не просто сообщение а MediaGroup, попробуйте проверить: print(message.media_group_id), и если сообщение это МедиаГруппа то собирать все file_id от медиа в список и отправлять с помощью send_media_group

Я уже пробовал, и чтобы я не вводил в принт я получал ошибку Telebot Creator Error:
name 'print' is not defined
